# Error running ASP Core on IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-10

okay, I created a ASP Core 2.0.5-Website and put it on my IIS-Server (Windows Server 2016), but every time I try to run it I get "**HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure**"

In the Windows-Events I get the following Error:

```
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/KASSENUTZER' with physical root 'C:\KasseUser\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\Kasse_UserAPI.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 80008081.
```

Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Kasse_UserAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: C25C6BB9-DA77-48E5-AF4E-1B6853F974F3-->
```

In the stdout-logfile I get the following

```
The application to execute does not exist: 'C:\KasseUser\Kasse_UserAPI.dll'
```

NOTE: To get this file I needed to change stdoutLogFile from ".\logs\stdout" to "..\logs\stdout". Otherwise I got the following Warning in the Windowsevents

```
 Warning: Could not create stdoutLogFile \\?\C:\KasseUser\logs\stdout_1888_20185394736.log, ErrorCode = -2147024891.
```

All directories exist and if I input "dotnet .\Kasse_UserAPI.dll" in cmd, it starts without Errors and can be accessed.

[Here is the Content of my Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hhgt.png)

I uploaded it by publishing the Project locally in visual Studio. Then Uploading it to the Server via Remotedesktop and putting it into the Server-Directory.

Comment: you have properly installed the "Hosting Bundle Installer" for IIS? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.0.6 If so, in order to have it taken into account, I had to restart IIS, or even my whole server at some point.

Comment: I did restart the Server multiple times, while trying to fix this, and yes. I have the Hosting bundle (DotNetCore.2.0.7-WindowsHosting.exe) installed

Comment: Can you provide the content of the folder C:\KasseUser\ ? Is it the result of a publish?

Comment: @Daboul I put a link to a png of the Directory in. And yes, I published it into a local Directory then copied it into the Server-Directory via Remotedesktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have no idea how, but I found a solution, I copied the c:\logs\ directory and deleted everything inside and named it KasseUser2, then put my project in it and changed the Directory in IIS to the new one, and now it works. No Idea why.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the credentials under which your IIS application pool is running your .NET Core web application that is different from the one used when you are running it directly with the dotnet command.

Comment: @Daboul maybe, but at the end i was running everything as admin, even the IIS-Page-Directories connected as admin :/